# ExceptionFilterAttribute may not be logging exceptions in ApplicationInsights

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-application-insights

Do exceptions that are filtered with a custom ExceptionFilterAttribute logged to Application Insights?

I want to return a custom DTO in my custom ExceptionFilterAttribute filter, but I think exceptions are no longer logged into ApplicationInsights after that. This is for .NET Core 3.0.

I added a line with:

```
this.telemetryClient.TrackException(context.Exception);
```

to make sure I can see the exception but I'm not sure if my exceptions are logged twice now.

Does anyone know if ApplicationInsights will log exception if they enter `ExceptionFilterAttribute`? I can't find documentation for this.

I'm calling just in case also:

```
base.OnException(context);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anyone know if ApplicationInsights will log exception if they
>   enter ExceptionFilterAttribute?

Yes, it will log the exceptions, so you do not need to add this line of code `this.telemetryClient.TrackException(context.Exception);`. Just using `base.OnException(context);` is ok.

You can see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/issues/289#issuecomment-497789201) for the similar issue, the reason is that "With new Ilogger enablement by default, exceptions are automatically reported by application insights.".

I also check it via a simple test, the test result as below:

[image]